# Binary semaphore to maintain concurrency

Tags: c, multithreading, posix, semaphore

I was trying to implement a multi-threaded program using binary semaphore. Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <semaphore.h>

int g = 0;

sem_t *semaphore;

void *myThreadFun(void *vargp)
{
    int myid = (int)vargp;
    static int s = 0;
    sem_wait(semaphore);
    ++s; ++g;
    printf("Thread ID: %d, Static: %d, Global: %d\n", myid, s, g);
    fflush(stdout);
    sem_post(semaphore);
    pthread_exit(0);
}

int main()
{   

    int i;
    pthread_t tid;
    if ((semaphore = sem_open("/semaphore", O_CREAT, 0644, 3))==SEM_FAILED) {
    printf("semaphore initialization failed\n");
    }


    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        pthread_create(&tid, NULL, myThreadFun, (void *)i);
    }

    pthread_exit(NULL);
    return 0; 
}
```

Now, when I opened the sempahore, I made the count 3. I was expecting that this wouldnt work, and I would get race condition, because each thread is now capable of decrementing the count.

Is there something wrong with the implementation? Also, if I make the count 0 during sem_open, wouldnt that initiate a deadlock condition, because all the threads should be blocked on sem_wait.

Comment: What is the return value of `sem_open("semaphore", O_CREAT, 0644, 1);`?

Comment: Have you looked at the manpage for `sem_open()`, especially what the meaning of the return value is?

Comment: It is not equal to SEM_FAILED

Comment: @EOF thanks for pointing out the problem. Yes, I didnt initialize sem_t* to sem_open. However, after initializing I do get right results, but when I increase the count to 3 or 4, i still get right results. I was expecting otherwise, because now each thread is capable of using sem_wait

Comment: Modified the question with the new query, as the old one was syntactically wrong.

Comment: Please don't just edit the code. Post the new code *in addition* to the old code. The bug also was *not* a syntax-error. Finally, if your semaphore is not initialized with a count of one, the behavior is undefined due to unsynchronized, non-readonly, non-atomic access to shared objects. The program may *appear* to work correctly, but it is not. One thing to remember is that `printf()` actually needs a lock, so this call may sometimes hide your error.

Comment: printf() is under the semaphore lock.

Comment: `printf()` *takes* a lock internally, since it is specified as thread-safe, but certainly will not be atomic in itself.

Comment: but I am flushing out the stdout in the lock itself..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109094/discussion-between-semantics-and-eof).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Now, when I opened the sempahore, I made the count 3. I was expecting that this wouldnt work, and I would get race condition, because each thread is now capable of decrementing the count.

And how do you judge that there isn't any race?  Observing output consistent with what you could rely upon in the absence of a data race in no way proves that there isn't a data race.  It merely fails provide any evidence of one.

However, you seem to be suggesting that there would be a data race *inherent* in more than one thread concurrently performing a `sem_wait()` on a semaphore whose value is initially greater than 1 (otherwise which counter are you talking about?).  But that's utter nonsense.  You're talking about a *semaphore*.  It's a synchronization object.  Such objects and the functions that manipulate them are the basis for thread synchronization.  They themselves are either completely thread safe or terminally buggy.

Now, you are correct that you open the semaphore with an initial count sufficient to avoid any of your threads blocking in `sem_wait()`, and that therefore they can all run concurrently in the whole body of `myThreadFun()`.  You have not established, however, that they in fact *do* run concurrently.  There are several reasons why they might not do.  If they do run concurrently, then the incrementing of shared variables `s` and `g` is indeed of concern, but again, even if you see no signs of a data race, that doesn't mean there isn't one.

Everything else aside, the fact that your threads all call `sem_wait()`, `sem_post()`, and `printf()` induces some synchronization in the form of memory barriers, which would reduce the likelihood of observing anomalous effects on `s` and `g`.  `sem_wait()` and `sem_post()` must contain memory barriers in order to function correctly, regardless of the semaphore's current count.  `printf()` calls are required to use locking to protect the state of the stream from corruption in multi-threaded programs, and it is reasonable to suppose that this will require a memory barrier.

> Is there something wrong with the implementation?

Yes.  It is not properly synchronized.  Initialize the semaphore with count 1 so that the modifications of `s` and `g` occur only while exactly one thread has the semaphore locked.

> Also, if I make the count 0 during sem_open, wouldnt that initiate a deadlock condition, because all the threads should be blocked on sem_wait.

If the semaphore has count 0 before any of the additional threads are started, then yes.  It is therefore inappropriate to open the semaphore with count 0, unless you also subsequently post to it before starting the threads.  But you are using a *named* semaphore.  These persist until removed, and you never remove it.  The count you specify to `sem_open()` has no effect unless a new semaphore needs to be created; when an existing semaphore is opened, its count is unchanged.

Also, do have the main thread join all the others before it terminates.  It's not inherently wrong not to do so, but in most cases it's required for the semantics you want.

Comment: First of all this statement, "you seem to be suggesting that there would be a data race inherent in more than one thread concurrently performing a sem_wait() on a semaphore whose value is initially greater than 1 (otherwise which counter are you talking about?). But that's utter nonsense."  You are calling it utter nonsense, and later contradicting it by saying that modification of global variables is a concern. That is what I initially presumed in the statement which you called nonsense.

Comment: Secondly, making the count 0 during sem_open doesnt cause the deadlock, i still get the output.

Comment: What you seem to be suggesting, and what is nonsensical, is that concurrent calls to `sem_post()` involve a data race, "because each thread is now capable of decrementing the count".  No count is decremented anywhere in your code, except for the semaphore's count of available leases.

Comment: By saying decrementing the count, I meant semaphore's count of available leases only. What else you think I would mean by decrementing the count? And since each thread is capable of decrementing the available leases, they all hold the capability of modifying the global variables

Comment: @Semantics, as I supposed, then.  That multiple threads can decrement the semaphore's count does not create any data race.  The semaphore implementation is thread safe.

Comment: What?? You yourself stated that they might run concurrently and modification of shared variables might be a concern.

Comment: @Semantics, as for your threads not blocking, you are using a *named* semaphore which you never remove.  Such a semaphore is persistent, so you keep reopening the same one.  Its value is set only when you create it.  I will clarify this point in my answer.

Comment: I agree with your explanation about count 0. if i use sem_init, which is unnamed sempahore, sem_wait gives me -1 and fails.

Comment: @Semantics, modifying the semaphore's count via the functions provided for that purpose is always thread safe.  This is a requirement on those functions and on the semaphore implementation.  It is completely different from incrementing shared variables `s` and `g`.

Comment: My concern here is not the inherent implementation, but the effect it would have on the global variables. And that is what I am trying to point out in the question. I am not doubting the semaphore implementation, No. I am just trying to understand as to why I didnt see race condition. But you have addressed it as well. Thank you.

Comment: Bear in mind, named semaphores persist beyond the life of the process - and if you happen to be using OSX the behaviour is inconsistent - you have to sem_unlink or else the count doesn't get reset even with a fresh call to sem_open O_CREAT.

Answer (score 0):

I'll get to the code in a bit that proves you had a race condition. I'll add a couple of different ways to trigger it so you can see how this works. I'm doing this on Linux and passing -std=gnu99 as a param to gcc ie

```
gcc -Wall -pedantic -lpthread -std=gnu99 semaphore.c -o semtex
```

Note. In your original example (assuming Linux) one fatal mistake you had was not removing the semaphore. If you run the following command you might see some of these sitting around on your machine

```
ls -la /dev/shm/sem.*
```

You need to make sure that there are no old semaphore sitting on the filesystem before running your program or you end up picking up the last settings from the old semaphore. You need to use `sem_unlink` to clean up.

To run it please use the following.

```
rm /dev/shm/sem.semtex;./semtex
```

I'm deliberately making sure that the semaphore is not there before running because if you have a DEADLOCK it can be left around and that causes all sorts of problems when testing.

> Now, when I opened the sempahore, I made the count 3. I was expecting
>   that this wouldn't work, and I would get race condition, because each
>   thread is now capable of decrementing the count.

You had a race condition but sometimes C is so damned fast things can **appear** to work because your program can get everything it needs done in the time the OS has allocated to the thread ie the OS didn't preempt it at an important point.

This is one of those cases, the race condition is there you just need to squint a little bit to see it. In the following code you can tweak some parameters to see the a deadlock, correct usage and Undefined Behavior.

```
#define INITIAL_SEMAPHORE_VALUE CORRECT
```

The value `INITIAL_SEMAPHORE_VALUE` can take three values...

```
#define DEADLOCK  0
#define CORRECT   1
#define INCORRECT 2
```

I hope they're self explanatory. You can also use two methods to cause the race condition to blow up the program.

```
#define METHOD sleep
```

Set the `METHOD` to `spin` and you can play with the `SPIN_COUNT` and find out how many times the loop can run before you actually see a problem, this is C, it can get a lot done before it gets preempted. The code has most of the rest of the information you need in it.

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/stat.h> 
#include <unistd.h>
#define DEADLOCK  0 // DEADLOCK
#define CORRECT   1 // CORRECT
#define INCORRECT 2 // INCORRECT
/*
 * Change the following values to observe what happen.
 */
#define INITIAL_SEMAPHORE_VALUE CORRECT
//The next value provides to two different ways to trigger the problem, one
//using a tight loop and the other using a system call.
#define METHOD sleep

#if (METHOD == spin)
/* You need to increase the SPIN_COUNT to a value that's big enough that the
 * kernel preempts the thread to see it fail. The value set here worked for me 
 * in a VM but might not work for you, tweak it. */
#define SPIN_COUNT 1000000
#else 
/* The reason we can use such a small time for USLEEP is because we're making
 * the kernel preempt the thread by using a system call.*/
#define USLEEP_TIME 1
#endif
#define TOT_THREADS 10

static int g = 0;
static int ret = 1729;
sem_t *semaphore;

void *myThreadFun(void *vargp) {
  int myid = (int)vargp;
  int w = 0;
  static int s = 0;
  if((w = sem_wait(semaphore)) != 0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error: %s\n", strerror(errno));
    abort();
  };
/* This is the interesting part... Between updating `s` and `g` we add
 * a delay using one of two methods. */
  s++;
#if ( METHOD == spin )
  int spin = 0;
  while(spin < SPIN_COUNT) {
    spin++;
  }
#else
  usleep(USLEEP_TIME);
#endif
g++;
  if(s != g) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Fatal Error: s != g in thread: %d, s: %d, g: %d\n", myid, s, g);
    abort();
  } 
  printf("Thread ID: %d, Static: %d, Global: %d\n", myid, s, g);
  // It's a false sense of security if you think the assert will fail on a race
  // condition when you get the params to sem_open wrong It might not be
  // detected.
  assert(s == g);
  if((w = sem_post(semaphore)) != 0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error: %s\n", strerror(errno));
    abort();
  };
  return &ret;
} 

int main(void){
  int i;
  void *status;
  const char *semaphore_name = "semtex";
  pthread_t tids[TOT_THREADS];
  if((semaphore = sem_open(semaphore_name, O_CREAT, 0644, INITIAL_SEMAPHORE_VALUE)) == SEM_FAILED) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Fatal Error: %s\n", strerror(errno));
    abort();
  }
  for (i = 0; i < TOT_THREADS; i++) {
    pthread_create(&tids[i], NULL, myThreadFun, (void *) (intptr_t) i);
  }
  for (i = 0; i < TOT_THREADS; i++) {
    pthread_join(tids[i], &status);
    assert(*(int*)status == 1729);
  }
  /*The following line was missing from your original code*/
  sem_unlink(semaphore_name);
  pthread_exit(0);
}
```

Comment: what is this code suppose to do? I mean I can read and try to understand, but what exactly is the point. Also, in sem_open, you didnt specify the count. Does it compile without warning?

Comment: @Semantics I've updated the code to make it a bit more explanatory. I hope this helps clear up everything. Ping me if you need to know anything more.